# Fourier coefficients of $f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{1+\cos z}$ through Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laurent-series

I had to find the Fourier coefficients of this simply periodic function $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{1+\cos (z)},$$
I proceeded considering the $w=exp(iz)$ and considering the Laurent expansion of the function $F(w)$
$$F\left(w\right)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2w}\left(w^{2}+1\right)}=\frac{2w}{\left(w+1\right)^{2}},$$
If I'm not making a mistake, this function has a Laurent expansion  in zero inside the unit circle given by
$$F\left(w\right)=\sum\left(-1\right)^{n}2\left(n+1\right)w^{n+1},\,\,\,n\geq0$$
So writing back fourier expansion for $f(z)$ I have the following Fourier expansion
$$f\left(z\right)=\sum c_{n}e^{inz},\,\,\,\,\,c_{n}=\left(-1\right)^{n}2n,\,\,\,\,n\geq1$$
I think everything is fine but when I'm doing the same analysis with an equivalent formulation of $f(z)$ I have a different result. Can anybody check for me if those I found are the real Fourier coefficients of my $f(z)$?

Comment: *What* equivalent formulation?

Comment: I used the bisection formula to eliminate the square on the cosine... but are those coefficients correct?

Comment: Your *Taylor* expansion of $F$ is correct.

Comment: can you also check in an indipendente way if the fourier coefficients are correct?

Comment: A problem: the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is 1. But $|e^{inz}|$ can be greater than 1.

Comment: yes I know, let's suppose we are inside the unit circle... I think I might have done some mistake in converting the original function

Comment: i think since the taylor expansion is valid for the unit circle, so the the fourier and taylor coefficients coincide, as for independent checking, you could just compute it the normal way, that is, by computing $\frac1{2\pi}\int f(z)e^{inz}dz$ on the unit circle

Comment: Integrating $\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^n 2n e^{inz}$ term to term, the primitive is a geometric series...